# Aggregation performance issue in Elasticsearch with hotel availability data

Tags: performance, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation

I am building a small app to find hotel room availability like booking.com using Elasticsearch 6.8.0.

Basically, I have a document per day and room, that specifies if it is available and the rate for that day. I need to run a query with this requirements:

Input:

- The days of the desired staying.
- The max amount of money I am willing to spend.
- The page of the results I want to see.
- The number of results per page.

Output:

- List of cheapest offer per hotel that fulfill the requirements, ordered in ASC order.

Documents schema:

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "_doc": {
      "properties": {
        "room_id": {
          "type": "keyword"
        },
        "available": {
          "type": "boolean"
        },
        "rate": {
          "type": "float"
        },
        "hotel_id": {
          "type": "keyword"
        },
        "day": {
          "type": "date",
          "format": "yyyyMMdd"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I have an index per month, and at the moment I only search within the same month.

I came up with this query:

```
GET /hotels_201910/_search?filter_path=aggregations.hotel.buckets.min_price.value,aggregations.hotel.buckets.key
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
         "range": {
            "day": { "gte" : "20191001", "lte" : "20191010" }
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "available": true
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "hotel": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "hotel_id",
        "min_doc_count": 1,
        "size" : 1000000
      },
      "aggs": {
        "room": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "room_id",
            "min_doc_count": 10,
            "size" : 1000000
          },
          "aggs": {
            "sum_price": {
              "sum": {
                "field": "rate"
              }
            },
            "max_price": {
              "bucket_selector": {
                "buckets_path": {
                  "price": "sum_price"
                },
                "script": "params.price <= 600"
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "min_price": {
          "min_bucket": {
            "buckets_path": "room>sum_price"
          }
        },
        "sort_by_min_price" : {
          "bucket_sort" :{
            "sort": [{"min_price" : { "order" : "asc" }}],
            "from" : 0,
            "size" : 20
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And it works, but have several issues.

- It is too slow. With 100K daily rooms, it takes about 500 ms to return on my computer, where no other query is running. So in a live system it would be very bad.
- I need to setup the `"size"` to a big number in the terms aggregation, otherwise not all hotels and rooms are considered.

Is there a way to improve the performance of this aggregation? I have tried to split the index in multiple shards, but it did not help.

I am almost sure that the approach is wrong, and that is why is slow. Any recommendation about how to achieve a faster query response time in this case?

Answer (score 1):

Before going to the answer, I didnt understand why you are using the below condition/aggregation

```
"min_price": {
          "min_bucket": {
            "buckets_path": "room>sum_price"
          }
        }
```

Can you give me more clarification on why you need this.

Now, the answer your main question:

Why do you want to term by room_id as well with hotel_id. You can get all the rooms of your search and then group them by hotel_id on application side.

The below logic, will get you all docs grouped by room_id and with sum metrics. You can use the same script filter for > 600 condition.

```
   {
      "size": 0,
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "filter": [
            {
             "range": {
                "day": { "gte" : "20191001", "lte" : "20191010" }
              }
            },
            {
              "term": {
                "available": true
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      "by_room_id": {
            "composite" : {
              "size": 100, 
                "sources" : [
                    { 
                      "room_id": { 
                        "terms" : { 
                          "field": "room_id" 
                        } 
                      } 
                    }
                ]
            },
            "aggregations": {
                "price_on_required_dates": {
                    "sum": { "field": "rate" }
                },
                "include_source": {
                    "top_hits": {
                "size": 1,
                "_source": true
              }
            },
            "price_bucket_sort": {
                "bucket_sort": {
                        "sort": [
                          {"price_on_required_dates": {"order": "desc"}}
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
     }
```

Also, to improve search performance, 
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/tune-for-search-speed.html

Comment: In other to provide the cheapest offer per hotel, I need to aggregate per hotel. Imagine that there is an hotel with 200 rooms at $1 per night each, then the first 100 results of any query would be about rooms in that hotel.

Comment: It is definitely faster your way :D I wonder if it is worth it at all to aggregate by hotel_id, and instead just do it in the client. That brings the complication that I need to maintain some state across calls about which hotels have been seen already.

Comment: After some testing the ordering does not work in your proposal. If you follow the "after_key" parameter, cheaper prices than the last in the previous page appears. Also considers rooms for which there ins no availability in some of the days.

Comment: @vtortola Are you referring to the rate field inside the source or aggregated field price_on_required_dates. This logic sort on the aggregated field and not on the rate field.

Comment: @Vlad Deciding on whether to do the group by hotel_id on application code or elasticsearch is based on the memory and space requirements you have.